# How to typecasting the object class from the dictionary value (object)

Tags: c#, json.net, jsonfx

How can I fix the typecast error...
I want to create new my object using by JSON..

I attached example code..

```
 public class Person
 {
     public int age;
     public Person(int _age)
     {
         this.age = _age;
     }
 }

 Dictionary<string, object> dic = new Dictionary<string, object>();
 dic.Add("type", "Person");
 dic.Add("data", new Person(25));

 string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dic);

 dic = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(json);

 Person p2 = (Person)dic["data"];
 Console.WriteLine(p2);
```

Comment: in with line you getting error?

Comment: I believe you don't need to pass "type" key into the dictionary. just create a simple array of persons and serialize and deserialize it. for checking "person' type, you can easily check a type of object by, typeof(), function.   In short, dont need to use dictioanary, you can simply use, List<Person> persons = new List<Person>(). then then add your person objects into it. And last, simply you can deserialize and serialize it.

Answer (score 1):

You getting dictionary of string,Person and casting to Person, thats why it is throwing an exception.

Try  `var person = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>((dic["data"].ToString()));`

instead of`Person p2 = (Person)dic["data"];`

And `person.age` will be `25`.

EDIT:

```
  public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Dictionary<string, object> dic = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            dic.Add("type", "Person");
            dic.Add("data", new Person(25));

            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dic);

            dic = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(json);
            var person = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>((dic["data"].ToString()));

            Console.WriteLine(person.age);
        }
```

Hope Helps!

Comment: Nope.. Y.Y  Console : 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary'2[System.String,System.Object] and saying korean blabla..  I did testing in TCP Socket Programming....

Comment: in My Debug mode.. I could see the dictionary value type that is System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,object>

Comment: I want this type parsing  : json string : {"protocolType":REQ_CONN,"data":Player Object } .. Player has a some variables..

Comment: Jamaxack !! So So too many much veryvery Thank you.. I'm so very happy.. !!!!!!!!! Thank you ! ! ! ! ! !  ^^

Comment: I got it. I want to be a grateful programmer who helped other people like you ! . and .. study in English first.. Y.Y .  Have a good day Jamaxack